# Twitter Bootstrap: Using Progress bar with Single File Upload

Tags: image, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

Using Twitter Bootstrap, How can I use Progress bar with File Upload as soon as I select the file to upload.

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap only provides the Progress Bar and you can modify the progress value with javascript. The rest is [FIle API (w3.org)](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#introduction) or Ajax + Server side [PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/session.upload-progress.php) for example). So Twitter Bootstrap itself doesn't provide that, check [blueimp file uploader (github)](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Image Upload with Preview and Progress Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13666243/twitter-bootstrap-image-upload-with-preview-and-progress-bar)